# How to convert public and private keys to Privacy-Enhanced Mail?

Tags: key, pem, crt, cer

The folder contains public and private keys. On my Windows operating system, I'm trying to execute this command

`certutil OUTPUT.pem`

But I am getting an error: "CertUtil: -dump command NOT EXECUTED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)". How should I run the command to get .pem file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`copy INPUT.crt + INPUT.key OUTPUT.pem`
You will receive a certificate in PEM format.